# Parse.com getting relationship data iOS

Tags: ios, relational-database, parse-platform

So I am working with Parse.com for an iOS app with relational data. I got the app set up so its saving relational data in 2 classes (user and agent). What I am trying to do is display the "agent" info (in parse the columns are name string, and email string) in a some labels so when logged in the app the "agent" info assigned to the user shows up. What I have is

```
    self.agentRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"agentRelation"];
    PFQuery *query = [self.agentRelation query];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
        }
        else {
            self.agent = objects;

        }
    }];
```

this should get the info from parse but not sure how to spit it out for instance the Name string into a label outlet from here.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `self.agent = objects;` are incorrect. "objects" here are an array of objects resulting from the query. In your case, this is an array with only 1 object (the agent object). You need to get the object from the list, and then get the properties from that object.

I've changed your code so that you get a reference to the agent object. I also set the name and email from the agent object on UILabels (that you need to create, or replace with the labels you have created already, if any).

```
self.agentRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"agentRelation"];
PFQuery *query = [self.agentRelation query];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
    }
    else {
        PFObject *agent = [objects lastObject];
        self.agentNameLabel.text = agent[@"name];
        self.agentEmailLabel.text = agent[@"email];
    }
}];
```